# Can Entity Framework automatically convert datetime fields to UTC on save?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime, asp.net-mvc-5

I am writing an application using ASP.NET MVC 5. All of my datetime that I am going to store in the database must be converted from local time zone to UTC timezone first.

I am not sure where is the best place to do during the request cycle.

I can convert each field to UTC in the controller after it passes the ViewModel rules. But I feel this is too much code/step that I have to do.

Is there a way in Entity Framework that will allow me to add a rule that automatically converts datetime to UTC before saving the changes?

This is the method that I wrote that will convert a giving datetime to UTC

```
public static DateTime? ConvertToUTC(DateTime? val, TimeZoneInfo destinationTimeZone = null)
{
        if (val != null)
        {
            var dateTimeToConvert = ConvertToDateTime(val);

            if (destinationTimeZone == null)
            {
                if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LocalTimeZone"] != null)
                {
                    destinationTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LocalTimeZone"]);
                }
                else
                {
                    destinationTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName);
                }
            }
            return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dateTimeToConvert, destinationTimeZone);

        }

        return null;
}
```

Comment: The best place is to do it from the client. Only the client knows what time zone they are in and it should be the responsibilyt of the client to send the date time as UTC or as a DateTimeOffset type. Do not do it on the server, at that point it is too late unless you can garuntee that all clients are running in the same time zone as the server (*could* work for an intranet web app). The same goes for sending datetimes, send them as UTC to the client and let the client convert to locale. There are client side libraries that handle this well like momentjs.

Comment: I know the user local timezone in the user profile. everything is derived out of it.

Comment: Do your users travel? What happens when user Bob travels from New York to L.A.? And then Bob commits something to the DB that has a DateTime as property or retrieves something that has a DateTime property? You then have to ensure that Bob has updated his timezone info before. Maybe that works if Bob moves to the new timezone but if bob is a traveler that frequents different timezones then this becomes difficult to manage.

Comment: Bob will have to update his profile. but in my case my users don't really travel. If I want to take your advice and trust the JS to give me UTC time zone. How would I convert the database value from UTC back to UTC at the server?

Comment: You misread me. JS should send a UTC date time OR a DateTimeOffset, not the timezone. So any datetimes passed between JS and the server would already be in UTC format. The server would not handle any conversion at all. All conversion would occur at the client. However if you still want to implement the solution server side give me 1 second, Ill post something.

Comment: Well, if the conversion is done on server side, then one possibility is to have 2 properties : one for UTC time and one for local time.

Or if you use different model classes for the view data and database data, you might do the conversion in the function that convert between models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way in Entity Framework that will allow me to add a rule that automatically converts datetime to UTC before saving the changes?

You can override the SaveChanges / SaveChangesAsync methods and execute conversion before those get called on the DbContext.

```
// on your DbContext type

public override int SaveChanges(){
    DateTimeUtcHelper.SetDatesToUtc(this.ChangeTracker.Entries());
    return base.SaveChanges();
}

class DateTimeUtcHelper{
    internal static void SetDatesToUtc(IEnumerable<DbEntityEntry> changes) {
        foreach (var dbEntry in changes.Where(x => ChangesToTrackList.Contains(new[] {EntityState.Added, EntityState.Modified}))){
            foreach (var propertyName in dbEntry.CurrentValues.PropertyNames){

                // using reflection add logic to determine if its a DateTime or nullable DateTime
                // && if its kind = DateTimeKind.Local or Unspecified
                // and then convert set the Utc value
                // and write it back to the entry using dbEntry.CurrentValues[propertyName] = utcvalue;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

You would need to add your own logic to ensure there are not instances where you are changing the DateTime on a change that did not come from a user (ie. make sure that by default your materialized DateTimes have the DateTimeKind.Utc flag set or .Local if you change it for the user).

---

**Edit**

The DbContext would also need access to the timezone on the users profile for that Request context that it is running in. Perhaps an overload of SaveChanges would be better suited so you can pass it in OR if you are using DI perhaps you could inject it into the created DbContext.

Comment: ChangesToTrackList is not defined.