# Is there a way to change the DateTimeOffset to UtcDateTime or LocalDateTime in Model or Dto definition classes?

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, datetime, entity-framework-core

I have a .NET 6 Web API using Entity Framework. Some endpoints receive objects containing a datetimeoffset attribute and the incoming values are in the form of local datetime.

The problem is, with the latest version of PostgreSql, datetimeoffset values can only take the datetimeoffset inputs in ...T+00 UTC format. So when my value is something like ...T+03, I'm unable to write that to the database.

This is my model class

```
public class MyModel : BaseEntity
{
    public DateTimeOffset MyDate { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my dto class

```
public class Dto : BaseDto
{
    public DateTimeOffset MyDate { get; set; }
}
```

**Temporary Solution**

For now I change the format every time I post to and get from database in my service class as follows:

**For post:**

```
myDto.MyDate = myDto.MyDate.UtcDateTime;
var myModel = _mapper.Map<MyModel>(myDto);
await _unitOfWork.MyModelContext.CreateAsync(myModel);
await _unitOfWork.SaveAsync();
//...
```

**For get:**

```
var myModels = await _unitOfWork.MyModelContext.GetAll();
foreach(var myModel in myModels)
    myModel.MyDate = myModel.MyDate.LocalDateTime;
//...

//or

var myModel = await _unitOfWork.MyModelContext.GetById(id);
myModel.MyDate = myModel.MyDate.LocalDateTime;
//...
```

I know that this is a bad approach. **I am wondering if it is possible to make this operation inside my Dtos or Models so that I don't need make this operation on each service.**

I am open to other suggestions as well.

Comment: Can this answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39418323/can-entity-framework-automatically-convert-datetime-fields-to-utc-on-save

Comment: Well I thought of that as well but I wasn't sure to use it in Save() since I have only a couple of models using DateTime/DateTimeOffset attribute. If I implement a control in Save(), wouldn't it work for each database insert/update? I think that's not as efficient as converting it in the service (definitely more generic though). Thanks to your comment I also realized that I shouldn't convert from DateTimeOffset to Local in the API because then it always takes the timezone of the API. Instead, I should make that in the client side.

Comment: Thanks for your response, and I think convert the date time offset in the client side is also a good choice. And at first I wanted to find a solution like [Convert Datetime] tag on the model property but failed.

Comment: I tried a similar approach on get and set of the models and dtos but that failed as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a [custom type converter](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html#custom-type-converters) like below.

```cs
public class DateTimeOffSetTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<DateTimeOffset, DateTimeOffset>
        {
            public DateTimeOffset Convert(DateTimeOffset source, DateTimeOffset destination, ResolutionContext context)
            {
                destination = source.UtcDateTime;
                return destination;
            }
        }
```

Then define it in your mapping configuration class.

```cs
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
      
      cfg.CreateMap<DateTimeOffset, DateTimeOffset>().ConvertUsing(new DateTimeOffSetTypeConverter());
      
      //your mapping configurations
    });
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you for the answer. I added the custom type converter and since I use "Profiles" for automapper configuration I just added this line into my related profile class as follows:             
"CreateMap<DateTimeOffset, DateTimeOffset>().ConvertUsing(new DateTimeOffSetTypeConverter());" Do you have any suggestion on the web app part as well? How should I handle it after receiving the objects from the API to show the utc times in local time? For now I implemented it in the relevant controller of the web application but I don't want to make it inside the foreach

Comment: I think using foreach loop and change just one value is suitable if you get your list as paginated. But maybe you can use the ForEach method of Linq `yourList.ForEach(c => c.MyDate = c.MyDate.ToLocalTime());`